# Can't install the newest versions of packages

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade

Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop LTS 32-bit (don't need to upgrade OS, so this version is ok for me)

```
anzipex@anzipex:~$ sudo apt update
anzipex@anzipex:~$ sudo apt upgrade
```

Then i've got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

150 additional updates are available with UA Infrastructure ESM.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable
See https://ubuntu.com/advantage or run: sudo ua status
```

And then:

```
anzipex@anzipex:~$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
anzipex@anzipex:~$ sudo ua status
SERVICE       AVAILABLE  DESCRIPTION
cc-eal        no         Common Criteria EAL2 Provisioning Packages
esm-infra     no         UA Infra: Extended Security Maintenance
fips          no         NIST-certified FIPS modules
fips-updates  no         Uncertified security updates to FIPS modules
livepatch     no         Canonical Livepatch service

This machine is not attached to a UA subscription.
See https://ubuntu.com/advantage
```

I don’t quite understand what the problem is. How to solve this problem so that I can again upgrade all the packages normally?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is **EoL**, but there is the ESM version that is off-topic here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit long to comment.

If you do not upgrade your OS, the newer version of the packages will be not available in your package repository. So, if you want to get newer version of the packages, you should consider upgrading your OS.

And by the way, about ESM.

ESM is a paid service that is provided by Canonical. You can purchase them if you want to stay with your current version of Ubuntu. They will release security updates.

Comment: ESM (through Ubuntu Advantage) is now available free within limits, 3 boxes for community members and 50 for Ubuntu Members - https://ubuntu.com/blog/ua-services-deployed-from-the-command-line-with-ua-client.

Comment: @Anzipex  If you continue to use 14.04 without ESM or release-upgrading to a supported release, you'll get no updates due to EOL status (or *end of standard support* in Canonical's current terminology*).  You also haven't had any security updates since end-April 2019 which won't be a problem if you're off-line, but be-aware and consider your security choices.  http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/